# How to display a JS asynchronous result when called on a loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, formatting, synchronous

I'm working on a personal project and I'm stuck on what seems to be a "basic" synchronous / asynchronous Javascript problem.

To sum it up, I'm calling an asynchronous API, then I display the result on screen.
The formatted desired result is : "At X kilometers from Y", where X is calculated and returned correctly from the API, and Y is the name of the place (which is not displayed correctly).

Here is my code, with some comments for a better comprehension :

```
//loadedLandmarks.length is **always** between 1 and 3. No exception.
//In this sample, let's say we have 3 items in loadedLandmarks
for(var i = 0 ; i < loadedLandmarks.length ; i++)
{
    var currentLandmarkName = loadedLandmarks[i].customInfo.Name;
    landmarksName.push(loadedLandmarks[i].customInfo.Name);

    //landmarkName contains the good names, for example : "My school", "My home", "My favorite nightclub" (here after 3 pass on the loop)
    console.log(landmarksName);

    //DisplayDistanceFromLandmarks is my method which calls the asynchronous API. It seems OK.
    DisplayDistanceFromLandmarks(pos, i).then(function(response) {
        //The response variable contains correct informations from the API
        var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
        var results = response.rows[0].elements;

        //I explain this line below
        console.log(loadedLandmarks)

        //Then I'm formatting the result to display it on screen (I only paste here the interesting part)
        distances += "<br />At " + results[0].distance.value + "kms from" + currentLandmarkName;

        return distances;
}).done( /*some other things*/ );
```

The results displayed are :

> At 5 kms from [insert here the LAST currentLandmarkName]
>   At 8.5 kms from [insert here the LAST currentLandmarkName]
>   At 0.2 kms from [insert here the LAST currentLandmarkName]

Whereas it should be :

> At 5 kms from [insert here the FIRST currentLandmarkName]
>   At 8.5 kms from [insert here the SECOND currentLandmarkName]
>   At 0.2 kms from [insert here the THIRD currentLandmarkName]

What I don't understand is, when I write `console.log(loadedLandmarks)`, the content of the Array is correct, with `loadedLandmarks[0].Name` = the first name, `loadedLandmarks[1].Name` = the second name etc.
However, `i` is always equals to 3, and `currentLandmarkName` is always equals to the last landmark name.
It seems they are overwritten, and I don't understand why.

I'm very new with JS and asynchronous problems, can someone explain me why I face this behavior, and, very important, how to correct it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
var DisplayDistance = function () {
        var currentLandmarkName = loadedLandmarks[i].customInfo.Name;
        landmarksName.push(loadedLandmarks[i].customInfo.Name);

        //landmarkName contains the good names, for example : "My school", "My home", "My favorite nightclub" (here after 3 pass on the loop)
        console.log(landmarksName);

        //DisplayDistanceFromLandmarks is my method which calls the asynchronous API. It seems OK.
        DisplayDistanceFromLandmarks(pos, i).then(function(response) {
            //The response variable contains correct informations from the API
            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
            var results = response.rows[0].elements;

            //I explain this line below
            console.log(loadedLandmarks)

            //Then I'm formatting the result to display it on screen (I only paste here the interesting part)
            distances += "<br />At " + results[0].distance.value + "kms from" + currentLandmarkName;

            i++;
            if (i < loadedLandmarks.length) {
                DisplayDistance();
            }

            return distances;
    }).done( /*some other things*/ );
}
DisplayDistance();
```

Comment: I just copy/paste your suggested modifications and it works perfectly, thanks a lot !! Some explainations with your piece of code could be better, but I'll try to understand with the other answers. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This method `DisplayDistanceFromLandmarks` is asynchronous which means it doesn't block the rest of the code execution. So by the time you form the html string `distances` in the callback like so:

```
distances += "<br />At " + results[0].distance.value + "kms from" + currentLandmarkName;
```

The `for` loop is already over and the callback function calls are queued and they return their values later on. The callback function doesn't have `currentLandmarkName` in its scope as it's defined like

```
var currentLandmarkName = loadedLandmarks[i].customInfo.Name;
```

There are two things you can do I feel:

1. Pass the variable `currentLandmarkName`into the `DisplayDistanceFromLandmarks` method thereby bringing it in scope.
2. You may also try to use a while loop and increment the counter i.e. the variable `i` only inside the callback. That way you are forcing the asynchronous behaviour to be synchronous. So the next iteration of the loop will only happen after the promise is resolved and callback is evaluated.

There is a really good article that I came across that explains this asynchronous behaviour of javascript and the idea of closures. You might wanna give it a read http://www.javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/

Hope it gets you started in the right direction. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, I'll need to read it more than once to understand I think =) I'll also take a look to your link, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Hy,
this is a typical problem with JavaScript and closures.

Inside the function passed to `DisplayDistanceFromLandmarks(pos, i).then()` you use the variable `currentLandmarkName` which is giving you some troubles.

This variable is not defined inside that function, but outside it in the `for` cycle:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < loadedLandmarks.length ; i++)
{
    var currentLandmarkName = loadedLandmarks[i].customInfo.Name;
    ...
```

For each call of the `for` cycle, you call `DisplayDistanceFromLandmarks(pos, i).then()` and inside the `then` call you define a new anonymous function. This function, when created, has a closure associated to it. Inside this closure there is a **reference** to  `currentLandmarkName`. **Note: there is a reference to the variable not its value**. Thanks to this reference, you can use it.

The problem is that the code is asyncronous, so the `then` function is called after the for loop is ended. When the `for` loop ends the `currentLandmarkName` has always the value of the last loadedLandmarks:

```
var currentLandmarkName = loadedLandmarks[i].customInfo.Name;
```

with `i` equal to `loadedLandmarks.length-1`.

So when the `then` function is called, it tries to access the reference of `currentLandmarkName` which is always equal to the last element:

```
 loadedLandmarks[loadedLandmarks.length-1].customInfo.Name;
```

For this reason you always get `[insert here the LAST currentLandmarkName]`.

Comment: It's not my first closure problem, I will take a deeper look on it. Thanks a lot for the explaination !